# Firebase HTTP Cloud Function - 500 Server Error, try again

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I have an HTTP function executed a few times a second (I don't have exact statistics).

Sometimes, the request will return data like intended, and sometimes it will return this error text:

```html
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

When this happens, this tends to happen for all of my HTTP functions. Making the same request 5 minutes later often works.

Now, I could have imagined its an error in my code, but I am using a middleware to catch all errors and respond as JSON!

Here is my exported cloud function:

```js
const app = express();
app.use(cors({origin: true, credentials: true})); // Allow cross-origin requests
app.get('/', this.reportRequest.bind(this));
app.use(errorMiddleware); // Handle errors

export const report = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

And here is the `errorMiddleware`:

```js
export const errorMiddleware: ErrorRequestHandler = async (e, req, res, next) => {
  const executionId = req.header('function-execution-id');

  const message = 'message' in e ? e.message : e;

  const code = e.code && e.code > 200 && e.code < 600 ? e.code : 500;
  res.status(code).json({message, executionId});

  next();
};
```

Comment: What are the errors you get? I've run into some issues with Cloud Functions and calling external APIs (Google APIs) too quickly. WIll start erroring out.

Comment: The errors I get are in the first code block, its just that HTML code, and status code 500. `The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.`. I'm not sure if I am calling the API too quickly. Is there a way to check this?

Comment: Could you give some more detail? What do you do with this function? Do you render a website inside the cloud function? I use Cloud Functions as backend for my web app so i get just errors from the request and not a html document.

Comment: I use firebase cloud functions as an API. This report function for example, lists a few items from cloud firestore and returns them as JSON. At no point I return HTML, nonetheless, this is the output. I suspect its something related to firebase, not the express function.

Comment: Maybe there it is a problem with the order of your code. As far as i know you have to put the app.use(middleware) before app.get() to get a JSON response because the code is sequential. But this will not explain the behavior why the function stops for 5 min. What does the reportRequest callback function do?

Comment: @Sebe so the last `use`  is an error handler, as of `express` spec. It works like this. `requestReport` just lists a few items from the cloud firestore database. It works usually, and gets accessed to a few times a second. But these outages with this error are unexpected.

Comment: Yes, it should work like this sorry. But i still think the problem is the error handling. The html response seems to come from the default error handler and your error handler is ignored. Maybe your function gets stuck because your mentioned 5 minutes matches the 300 seconds function timeout. Could you open your cloud function logs and check if the function with the error finishes or get stuck.

Comment: The function does not finish, the function never starts in the logs. I wrote that if I try again after 5 minutes, it works, but when I try and get an error, the error is instantaneous - no wait time, error 500

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210900/discussion-between-sebe-and-amit).

Comment: Could be a cloud function cold start problem?

Comment: @Claudio How can I check if this is the case?

Comment: @Amit when you open the cloud function page, and under "general" section you can select the active instances. You can see if new cloud function instance is started and when. You can check if your problems happen when the new instance is started.

Comment: Thanks, @Claudio, looking at the GCP logs, rather than firebase logs, I see this error "function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Function invocation was interrupted."  I inspected the rest of the logs with the same execution ID, the only other log comes 24 seconds before, saying "Function execution started"

Comment: @Amit checkout your cloud function configuration, is it possibile that your function has 25 seconds of timeout? So after this time is terminated by the Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: @Claudio Not possible. It has 60 seconds timeout, and if it would end with a timeout the error is different

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please check [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/117181234) and star it in order to receive updates regarding the status of this issue.

Some people agree with you that the error is happening somewhere in the middleware even before it hits the function and others believe that requests seem to be load-balanced to instances before they are able to respond.

A workaround would be to implement exponential backoff that identifies this error message and retries after incrementally longer time delays.

There is no ETA for the fix at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I've just met the same Issue, I need to upgrade the memory of my function from 2Go to 8Go, and after this upgrade I received 500 error on 30% of my invocation (with no error in the google log)

I rollback to 2Go and I don't get 500 error anymore...